# "Incomplete" Equatable implementation (Swift)

Tags: swift, equatable

Is it a good idea to implement the `Equatable` protocol for a Swift struct in a way to compare only ID-s (which is supposed to be unique) and ignore the rest of the properties? What are drawbacks of this approach?

```
struct Person {

    let id: String
    let name: String
    var surname: String
}

extension Person: Equatable {

    static func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

Comment: Only *you* can tell if the id uniquely identifies a person or not.

Comment: Agree with @MartinR, it's up to you to decide which properties to use to check for equality. In this particular case if ids are unique then you're good to go.

Comment: Isn't there any unspoken rule that equality algorithm should go through all the properties and if you have shortcuts, they should be implemented on a higher level of abstraction?

Comment: No, as long as you design things so that a different id means a different person and the same id means the same person you can absolutely use the id for equality checks

Comment: Or wouldn't it be a problem that two objects are equal (because they have the same ID-s) but have different `hashValue`-s (because the rest of properties differ)? Should I also override `var hashValue: Int`?

Comment: But they shouldn't have the same id but different properties, that is kind of the point!

Comment: A better approach in this case might be to make Person a class, have a manager object, and only allow one instance for each person

Comment: What would it mean for two people to have the same id but different names? If that is possible in your code I would say it is a problem

Comment: @simonWasHere a list of persons I receive from a server. An ID uniquely identifies each of them. There's even no editing on the client. I'm thinking of a situation when a name changes on the client and I still have a person with a deprecated name in memory. Looks like I will be stuck forever with the initial name. Right?

Comment: See my comment above, I would make person a class, have a person manager that stores them, and you could check if you have an updated version of an existing person when you get data from the server

Comment: @simonWasHere thanks, I'll give it a try.